# Are these uses of "cut (hair)" right? What are the differences in their meanings?

Tags: difference, linking-verbs

I told the stylist I wanted my hair cut short.

I told the stylist I wanted my hair to be cut short.

I told the stylist I wanted that my hair be cut short.

Comment: avoid ambiguity, go for the second one. 'hair cut' is a noun and what you want here is hair + *verb* to **make them** short!

Comment: I have just seen the first at the Oxford Dictionary Advanced Learners

Comment: Is HAIR CUT a noun here??

Comment: No, "haircut" is the noun.

Comment: @nima_persian that's why I said, avoid ambiguity. *hair cut* is noun and *(hair) (cut)* is (noun) + (verb)! The latter one is what might have found.

Comment: ???I am confused so much yet...

Comment: @MaulikV First example is not ambiguous (see BobRodes comment) and would be understood with the intended meaning. This would be a confusing way to say that you wanted your haircut to take less time, but is a perfectly valid and idiomatic way to say you want your hair to be cut to a short length.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Well, I'd prefer using *quickly* over *short* to have lesser time. Anyway, ignore that; you still came up with other meaning for the sentence 1. That's what I again say, if you say sentence 2, it means **only** one thing what the OP is concerned about!

Comment: @MaulikV Availability of alternate interpretations is why we have puns (also—one last time—it's _not_ ambiguous in writing, where the noun “haircut” is visually distinguishable from the verb “cut” applied to the noun “hair”). The facts remain that most native speakers would use the first example's phrasing because it is efficiently sufficiently clear. I grant you that it would be even more clear to phrase it “I told the hairstylist that I wanted the hair growing from the top of my head to be cut, piece by piece, until it was generally shorter than the average length of hair.” but nobody would.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is idiomatic and most in use.  There is no ambiguity in its meaning to a Native speaker.

The second one is less often seen; since the first gets across the same meaning the other two words aren't necessary.  It might be used as emphasis, though.  If you didn't think that the hair was cut short enough, then perhaps you would use "to be" to lengthen the sentence and in so doing add a little force to it.

The third one uses the subjunctive, which of course can be used to express desire or preference.  However, we don't use this construction with "want".  I suspect that "I want that he be happy" will sound as funny to other native speakers as it does to me.

"I told the hair stylist that I preferred that my hair be cut short" would be a more common use of subjunctive mood.  Probably even more common is "I told the hair stylist that I preferred that she cut my hair short" (note "cut" instead of "cuts"); since the hair stylist is actively involved in the sentence (she's the one cutting the hair) we probably would include her directly by using the active voice instead of the passive.

Now, let's talk about "hair cut" vs. "haircut".  "I like my hair cut short" and "I like a short haircut" mean the same thing.  The "to be" is understood in the first sentence.   There is no ambiguity to a native speaker as to whether short refers to how long the hair is or how long the haircut takes.  It means short hair.  If you are talking about a short period of time to cut hair, you would say "I like a quick haircut" or "I like my hair cut quickly."

Answer (score 2):

*Want* does license marked infinitive clauses as complements. Since in this case the infinitive is the copula *BE*, it may be omitted:

> I told the stylist I wanted my hair to be cut short.
>   I told the stylist I wanted my hair cut short.

These are equivalent.

*Want* does **not** license *that ...VERB<sup>finite form</sup>* clauses as complements. You may **not** say:

> I told the stylist I wanted that my hair be cut short.

It does, however, license active infinitive clauses with a subject:

> I told the stylist I wanted her to cut my hair short.

It also licenses NP complements, with no verb:

> I told the stylist I wanted a short haircut.

This complement can also be expressed as a predication, a clause with an (optional) infinitive copula:

> I told the stylist I wanted my haircut short.
>   I told the stylist I wanted my haircut to be short.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I can not find what you is you are saying

Comment: As I had told once, is there simpler way to explain the answer to a person who's not so familiar with technical jargon? Your answers are very detailed and give *in-depth* knowledge, which at times, is more than what the OP wants to know.

Comment: @nima_persian The simplest possible answer is that your first two sentences are grammatical and mean exactly the same thing. Your third sentence is not grammatical. Explaining **why** this is so takes some technical knowledge of English syntax. If you would like me to set out that knowledge I will do so.

Comment: Thank you so much. I start it with my normal knowledge. As far as I know, we can make subjunctive with the verb WANT. That to say, I want that is a subjunctive.

Comment: In addition, I do not know yet about HAIR CUT that is a verb here or no?

Comment: I want that you be here. I want you to be here. the first one is subjunctive and the second is not

Comment: @nima_persian Yes, but you are not allowed to use *that + subjunctive* with *want*. That is what *license* means: to permit. Each English verb licenses different kinds of clauses. ... *Cut* is a verb (usually). *Hair* is a noun. A *haircut* is also a noun. *Hair cut* is just a noun and a verb stuck together.

Comment: @nima_persian In *I want you to be here*, *to be* is a marked infinitive - it is 'marked' with the particle *to*. In *I will be there*, *be* is an unmarked infinitive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13657/discussion-between-nima-persian-and-stoneyb)

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB said above,
The verb 'want' doesn't agree with finite verbs. (Verbs without 'to' in front of them)
However 'want' agrees with infinitives (verbs with 'to' before them : as in 'to cut')
So using,

> I told the stylist I wanted my hair to be cut short.

is the best bet.

> I told the stylist I wanted my hair cut short.

describes how your hair should be, not what should be done with them.

Comment: I EVEN wonder which one  hair cut or haircut is right here? In addition, I EVEN do not know hair is verb or not here? SO ON.

Comment: I mean that I tediously need your explanations in details. And, no body has not YET answered my ORIGINAL QUESTION.

Comment: 'hair cut' is a phrase containing a noun+verb combination. 'haircut' is a noun. 'hair' is also a noun.'cut' is a verb

Comment: Thank you all so much. But your answer are very scatter--as I am just a learner and am not native speaker

Comment: Like I said in my answer, the third sentence is wrong The first and second are correct. The first one tells the stylist how your hair should be. The second one tells the stylist what should be done with your hair.